# Calculating the slope with changing y-values

Tags: r, loops, math

So I have an intuition of how to solve this task, but I'm in doubt of how to calculate it in R:
I need to output the beta values of a model of growth and vote (growth = x, vote = y). The trick is, that I want to add +1 to each y-value, one by one, and make 16 models in order to see how this influences the beta values.

I guess a loop would solve this, but I'm not sure how.

I calculate the slope using this formula:

```
betaHat <- (sum(((data$growth)-mean(data$growth))*data$vote))/
            (sum(((data$growth)-mean(data$growth))^2)) # vote = y, growth = x
```

```
   year growth  vote inc_party_candidate other_candidate
1  1952   2.40 44.60           Stevenson      Eisenhower
2  1956   2.89 57.76          Eisenhower       Stevenson
3  1960   0.85 49.91               Nixon         Kennedy
4  1964   4.21 61.34             Johnson       Goldwater
5  1968   3.02 49.60            Humphrey           Nixon
6  1972   3.62 61.79               Nixon        McGovern
7  1976   1.08 48.95                Ford          Carter
8  1980  -0.39 44.70              Carter          Reagan
9  1984   3.86 59.17              Reagan         Mondale
10 1988   2.27 53.94           Bush, Sr.         Dukakis
11 1992   0.38 46.55           Bush, Sr.         Clinton
12 1996   1.04 54.74             Clinton            Dole
13 2000   2.36 50.27                Gore       Bush, Jr.
14 2004   1.72 51.24           Bush, Jr.           Kerry
15 2008   0.10 46.32              McCain           Obama
16 2012   0.95 52.00               Obama          Romney
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lm for directly linear regression and beta.

```
for(ii in 1:16)
{
  x = data$growth
  y = data$vote
  y[ii] = y[ii] + 1

  reg = lm(y ~ x)
  print(reg$coefficients)

  # for without intercept you can do..
  reg = lm(y ~ x - 1)
  print(reg$coefficients)
}
```